# How to replace Visual Studio's integrated help with a browser-based web search?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load search URL in browser from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334212/load-search-url-in-browser-from-visual-studio)

Pressing F1 in VS launches Microsoft's Document Explorer. How can I open the help results in my web browser instead?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the Options, under Help / Online.

There you can select 
- try online first, then local

And you can select multiple providers to search in.

Comment: I edited the question so my intention is clearer.

Comment: still what he says is right. You can set the option search online only and it'd pop up firefox with the search, provided it is your default provider.

Comment: You can specify in VS.NET that the internal help viewer should be used instead of the external one, which is maybe a bit faster.

Comment: It still opens up Microsoft Document Explorer and i don't see how to change that.

Comment: Yeah, bascially integrated and external help viewer just determines whether the help window is a tab or seperate window.  A bit pointless with 2010 as you could just snap the window out.