# How do I search MSDN in the default browser when pressing F1 in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In 2010 if I press F1 then VS will open the MSDN help page for the object on which the cursor lies. It even passes the target framework in the query string so you get the correct page of the documentation. I want exactly this behaviour in 2008 but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Right now it will open the help page in an integrated viewer or an external viewer (depending on the setting *Options → Environment → Help → Show Help using* but both are ugly-looking and use some very old CSS styles. I just want it to open in my default browser.

The URL is right there in the viewer so I know it's just a matter of extracting that in a macro and opening the default browser, or finding some very well-hidden setting that makes VS do it itself.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930962/customization-for-visual-studio-2008-that-opens-msdn-help-in-a-browser-when-hitt) is similar but never got a good answer, and I don't consider [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334212/load-search-url-in-browser-from-visual-studio) to be suitable as I want to go directly to the correct MSDN page, not search Google/Bing/whatever for the object name.

Comment: VS2008 was only designed to work well with the MSDN library installed on your machine.  Which is a good way to use it, it's a heckofalot faster than a browser and it won't stop working randomly like the MSDN site does.  Download is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20955

Comment: I don't mind the minor overhead of a page load (internet connection is more than fast enough), and the MSDN website has never not been working when I wanted to use it, **and** I'm guaranteed to have the latest version if I use the website. Thanks for the suggestion/link though.

Answer (score 3):

The first link has a good suggestion.  Remove the key binding for F1, write a macro & then map the macro to F1.  The second link has another macro sample.

http://s344.codeinspot.com/q/1309159

[Load search URL in browser from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334212/load-search-url-in-browser-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2013 I am using external tools for this.  Click Tools/External/Add. For the URL you can use this

```
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=$(CurText)
```

[image]

Then you can bind a key to the external tool.